Calculation with transformation of coordinate
The following content comes from David Tong lecture notes on Quantum Hall Effect, p. $34-35$.

The resulting Berry Curvature in polar coordinates is
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\theta \phi} = \frac{\partial A_{\phi}}{\partial \theta} - \frac{\partial A_{\theta}}{\partial \phi} =
-\sin\left(\,\theta\,\right)
$$
This is simpler if we translate it back to cartesian coordinates where the rotational symmetry is more manifest. It becomes
$$
\mathcal{F}_{ij}\left(\,\vec{B}\,\right) = -\epsilon_{ijk}\, \frac{B^{k}}{2\left\vert\,\vec{B}\,\right\vert^{3}}
$$
My question is, how do we get the last equality
$$
\mathcal{F}_{ij}\left(\,\vec{B}\,\right) = -\epsilon_{ijk}\,\frac{B^{k}}{2\left\vert\,\vec{B}\,\right\vert^{3}}
$$
by starting from the specrical coordinate ?.
It seems to me that $\sin\left(\,\theta\,\right)$ would corresponds to
$$
\sin(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{\,x^{2} + y^{2}\,}}{\sqrt{\,x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}\,}}
$$
So we get Berry Curvature in the normal coordinate as
$$
\mathcal{F}_{ij}\left(\,\vec{B}\,\right) =
-\sin(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{\,x^{2} + y^{2}\,}}{\sqrt{\,x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}\,}}
$$
But actually this is not true. So in which step did I get wrong ?.

